# Simple Netty Http-Server returns only "Hello World"

Tags: java, http, netty, httpserver

It looks like the `Netty Http-Server` is just doing one thing:
When it is requested at `somedomain/hello` it will return "`Hello World`" string.

It will be appreciated if someone give me advice on the problem.

Answer (score -1):

It is a [hello world netty](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http2/helloworld) example. You can find on google by searching `netty hello world`.